# W/Choreographer(11277): Frame time is 13.988632 ms in the future! Check that graphics HAL is generating vsync timestamps using the correct timebase

Tags: flutter, dart

```
W/Choreographer(11277): Frame time is 13.988632 ms in the future!  Check that graphics HAL is generating vsync timestamps using the correct timebase.
```

This is the error produce at run time.
Flutter is not updating `setState` content and giving this error,
The code is given below

```
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          title: Center(child: Text('Dicee')),
        ),
        body: MyApp(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int leftDiceNumber = 1;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    leftDiceNumber = 4;
    return Center(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  leftDiceNumber = (Random().nextInt(6) + 1);
                  print('images/dice$leftDiceNumber.png');
                });
              },
              child: Image.asset('images/dice$leftDiceNumber.png'),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  leftDiceNumber = 5;
                });
              },
              child: Image.asset('images/dice6.png'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

please help me out of this

Comment: Were you trying to use multiple Firebase projects in your app? I'm getting the same error now

Comment: I have a same problem>
W/Choreographer(15216): Frame time is 0.084912 ms in the future!  Check that graphics HAL is generating vsync timestamps using the correct timebase.

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

I have also encountered this situation, and I have consulted many documents and found that this is not the problem caused by Flutter.

There is a possibility that the time of development environment and running environment is inconsistent.

**I modified the time zone and time of the running equipment to be consistent with the development environment, and restarted the running equipment, which solved the problem perfectly.**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. My solution was to open up Device Manager in Android Studio, go to the virtual device and Wipe Data.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was a type mismatch error which apparently the logger could not catch.
I was using `int` in my Model class whereas in firestore the value was in `String`.

Syncing their types resolved the error!

Answer (score -1):

I had this error when trying to use two Firebase projects in my app. It seems that a lot of the [Firebase data is persisted between restarts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66899145/flutter-unhandled-exception-core-duplicate-app).

To fix it, I had to comment out my call to Firebase.initializeApp() and run the app once. This seemed to clear out whatever was causing the error.

Comment: What is firebase and how does it relate to this question?